Asynchronously filled in table doesn't have any values in the fields
I'm working with a software suite called LaserFiche.
I'm trying to force it to do what I want, specifically, I want to put the contents of a hidden table into another table that I'm going to do a JQueryUI.Tabs function on.
Laserfiche has a custom event called "lookupcomplete".
$(document).on("lookupcomplete",function(e) {}
Anyway, inside that function I copy the HTML and paste into another div that I run .tabs() on. It copies the row but now the values.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Submit').hide();
  $('#tabs').hide();
   $(document).on("lookupstarted", function (event) {
    console.log('Started');
  });
  $(document).on("lookupcomplete",function(e) {
    fillTabs();
  });
});

function fillTabs() {
    $('#gage-history').html($('#q33').html()); //q33 is the asynchronously filled in table
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('#tabs').show();
}



How do I get at the values in the cells that were filled in by Ajax?


Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is #q33? Please provide a [mcve].

I was not able to replicate the issue as you reported it. I did make a test case that should be similar.


$(function() {
  function fillTab(source, target) {
    $(target).html($(source).html());
  }

  $("#trigger").click(function() {
    fillTab("#hidden_holder", "#tabs-1");
    $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
  });

  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna
      ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum.
      Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="hidden_holder">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Example 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="example" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="trigger">Trigger</button>



When you update the Tab, if you do it after it has been initialized, you may need to call refresh. I tested in FireFox and it seems to work as expected.
https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh
